# How to point VS2017 to the (arm-none-eabi-) gcc default headers when using cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a project/test out cmake with arm-none-eabi-gcc as my compiler using VS2017 (and VS2019RC/preview).

I am having difficulties in telling VS2017 where to look for the default gcc headers.

What is the correct/easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe with a toolchain file?

Comment: I've tried this. To no avail. Both through `CMakeSettings.json`'s cmakeToolchain argument or as a `variables` in that same .json file

Answer (score 0):

I know I can include them like regular includes but tried to look for configuration options and found below link on how to push it to INCLUDE env variable.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/arm-gcc-cross-compilation-in-visual-studio/

*You can specify additional include directories, but note that subdirectories when present must also be explicitly declared at this time.*

```
[code lang=”js”]
{
// The "environments" property is an array of key value pairs of the form
// { "EnvVar1": "Value1", "EnvVar2": "Value2" }
"environments": [
{
"INCLUDE": "${workspaceRoot}\\src\\includes"
}
],

{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "inheritEnvironments": [
        "gcc-arm"
      ],
      "name": "gccarm",
      "includePath": [
        "${env.INCLUDE}"
      ],
      "defines": [
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for not coming back at you in time, but sadly this doesn't work. What does work, but is not a solution (a real solution) is specifying the include paths in my cmake file. I'll answer my own question for now, but won't accept it.

Answer (score 0):

So I've got a workaround, that, well, works. But it is definitely not a long-term solution.

What i've done is added the GCC include paths directly in the `CMakeLists.txt`'s `target_include_directories` directive, and that works. Like so:

```
target_include_directories(
    ${ELF}
    PRIVATE
        "source"
        "source/target/arm/stm32f1/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/arm-none-eabi"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include/c++/7.3.1/backward"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/include"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/include-fixed"
        "${tools}\\bin\\../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/7.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/include"
)
```

But yeah, nobody wants such a solution. So if someone has a better idea?